# Logic Behind Linked Lists Using Dictionaries and Procedural Programming - Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, linked-list

I have successfully created a function that moves a node at a particular index to the front of a linked list, however I have some questions about the logic. First of all, my code is presented below:

```
def movePos(lst, index):
    counter=0
    ptr=lst
    new_node={}
    while counter != (index-1):
        ptr=ptr['next']
        counter+=1
    new_node['data']=ptr['next']['data']
    ptr['next']=ptr['next']['next']
    new_node['next'] = lst
    return new_node
```

If I have a linked list like:

```
myList={'data': 10, 'next': 
{'data': 9, 'next':
{'data': 7, 'next':
{'data': 4, 'next': None}}}}

>>>movePos(myList, 2)
{'data': 7, 'next': 
{'data': 10, 'next': 
{'data': 9, 'next': 
{'data': 4, 'next': None}}}}
```

I know that dictionaries behave weirdly in that if I have dictA={1:1} and dictB=dictA, if I change dictB, then it changes dictA. But with pointers, given that you are setting them equal to the list, when you are reassigning the pointer in the loop, why is it that the original linked list isn't losing a bunch of data values? If ptr=ptr['next'], why then isn't lst=lst['next']?
Example:

```
>>>a={'data':1,'next':{'data':4,'next':None}}
>>>b=a
>>>b=b['next']
>>>print(b)
{'data':4, 'next': None}
>>>print(a)
{'data':1,'next':{'data':4,'next':None}}
>>>b['data']=5
>>>print(a)
{'data':1,'next':{'data':5,'next':None}}
```

Comment: "I know that dictionaries behave weirdly..." Nope. **All Python objects behave in this way**. Also, Python doesn't have pointers.

Comment: If that's the case, then can you explain to me why ptr=ptr['next'] doesn't affect the linked list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Also, they are "pretend pointers." It's more for the sake of understanding them for future courses in Java and C.

Comment: Because *assignment is not mutation*. You are simply assigning the value of `ptr['next']` to `ptr`. Please read Ned Batchelder's [Facts and Myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers either, and I don't really see how this would help you understand C pointers. For the sake of understanding, you should understand that *Python doesn't have pointers*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, this is for a course, and I guess this is the easiest way to teach linked lists in an introductory programming course without delving into O.O.P. I know, it's silly, but thank you for the read.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly silly for a course that doesn't want to get into writing classes. But anyways, I also suggest reading [this link](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/). The analogy that python variables act like name-tags whereas in languages like C, variables act like boxes that hold values, is a good mental model.